# cin.getline() waiting for input

Tags: c++, eclipse, string, cin, getline

I'm a beginner making a program in `Eclipse IDE (C++)` and I've got a problem with a small piece of my code. The problem is shown below:

```
char dataArray[100];

cout<<"Please enter a data set string: ";
cin.getline(dataArray,100,'\n');
cout<<dataArray;
```

When I run it the program gets stuck at the `getline` command, whatever the input, it just lets me input characters indefinitely without continuing.

Comment: I don't suppose you pressed the enter/return key somewhere in all those keystrokes ?

Comment: Is the same behavior exhibited run from a console as opposed to the Eclipse IDE ? The posted code, fixed to include the right headers and namespace slurp, runs exactly as you would expect under netbeans, Xcode, and a console. Just fyi.

Comment: Just thought myself that it's probably the IDE, i'll test it on my laptop.

Comment: Yup, looks like it was the Eclipse IDE, thanks. Any ideas on how to fix that? Pretty used to Eclipse, don't want to be changing.

Comment: Sry, but I don't use it (IDEA, Netbeans, DevStudio, and Xcode; just about everying *but* Eclipse). Hunt around, there's bound to be a related question somewhere on SO (I hope).

Comment: Looks like Eclipse isn't that popular, for C++ at least. Could you recommend me one as a beginner?

Comment: Have you tried doing `Ctrl+C`?

Comment: yes makes no difference

Answer (score 0):

You are reading data from `input stream` or from `dataArray` ? Standard format of getline is

```
 istream& getline (istream& is, string& str, char delim);
```

Where `is` is `istream` object from which characters are extracted

```
 std::string data;
 std::getline (std::cin,data);
```

try this.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I don't get this. However it turns out it was the IDE's problem.